# How to change AddForce code to MovePosition or SetVelocity?

Tags: unity, c#

```
Vector2 vec = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical);
    vec = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(vec, 1f);

    Vector3 camF = cam.transform.forward;
    Vector3 camR = cam.transform.right;

    camF.y = 0;
    camR.y = 0;
    camF = camF.normalized;
    camR = camR.normalized;

    targetPosition = (camF * vec.y + camR * vec.x) * MoveSpeed;

    Vector2 targetVelocity = (targetPosition - transform.position)/Time.deltaTime;

    rb.AddForce(targetPosition - rb.velocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
```

My problem is my character doesn't affects by the gravity when i changed my code from `transform.position` to `rb.AddForce`. I searched online and even asked here how to calculate gravity and add it to my character, nobody knew, so i think if i can change this code to `rb.MovePosition` or `rb.SetVelocity` maybe it does affects by the gravity?

Comment: Do you know about `Rigidbody.useGravity` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-useGravity.html ?

Comment: This code already sets velocity / moves to a target position. The fact that it's being done with AddForce isn't the problem. The problem, as I told you previously, is that you've decided to model your control strategy on an authoritative target position and then chose not to include any model of gravity when computing that position. So naturally you don't get gravity out: it just moves to the position you asked for. Did you try the method I linked you to earlier, thinking of your control as a target motion rather than a target position?

Comment: I tried and even asked you how to fix this but you said "That's sounds like a new question" so here i am

Comment: No, you ignored the link I offered and asked something unrelated, which is why I told you it was an unrelated question. I recommend that you stop asking about your guessed solution (it's not substituting `position` for `AddForce` or `MovePosition` or anything like that) and start asking about the problem you want to solve: moving a character while preserving gravity. This helps you avoid the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and fix the root cause that's causing you problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing the gravity when you subtract `rb.velocity` from `targetPosition`

Try doing it like this instead:

```
Vector2 vec = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical);
vec = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(vec, 1f);

Vector3 camF = cam.transform.forward;
Vector3 camR = cam.transform.right;    

camF.y = 0;
camR.y = 0;

camF = camF.normalized;
camR = camR.normalized;

targetVelocity = (camF * vec.y + camR * vec.x) * MoveSpeed;

Vector3 horizontalVelocity = rb.velocity;
// Zero out the y so that we don't compute a vertical velocity change.
horizontalVelocity.y = 0;

rb.AddForce(targetVelocity - horizontalVelocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
```